# Numismatist or philatelist assists investigation of black woman involved in biosphere experiment in Arizona (short story in Asimov's, mid 1980s)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story contains a rich young man who was either a numismatist or philatelist. His assistance is sought by a young woman (white) who is trying to determine what another woman (black - described as looking like a golliwog doll) is doing. The black woman is part of a biosphere experiment in Arizona, and I seem to recall that her followers are almost like a cult. I cannot recall why the white woman is investigating the other woman for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Identify short story that appeared in Isaac Asimov's magazine in the mid 1980s**

["Destroyer of Worlds"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42340), a novella by [Charles Sheffield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Sheffield), first published in [*Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine*, February 1989](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59163+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v13n02_1989-02).

**The story contains a rich young man who was either a numismatist or philatelist.**

He was a philatelist:

> After a few moments he sighed. "All right, all right. I'll help you look for Jason Lockyer. And why do I run the stamp store? I'll tell you, I do it to *avoid* conversations like this—with my own damned family. They're all over-achievers, and they went on at me for years, telling me to go out and change the world—run for public office, or buy a position on the New York Stock Exchange, or win a Nobel Prize." His voice was becoming steadily louder. I don't want to do *any* of those things. I want a nice, peaceful life, looking at interesting things. And no one else is willing to let me do that! That's one nice thing about stamps. The family accepts that I'm running a business, they stay away and the stamps don't *harass* you."

**His assistance is sought by a young woman (white) who is trying to determine what another woman (black - described as looking like a [golliwog doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golliwog)) is doing.**

No, she is looking for a missing man. She (the white woman, Rachel Banks) narrates the story; here she introduces herself to the rich young philatelist:

> "I'm a private investigator," I said. "Here's my credentials."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "I'm investigating the disappearance of Jason Lockyer," I said. I *was* nervous, no doubt about it. Eleanor Lockyer had that effect on me.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "Lockyer is a biologist," I went on. "A specialist in algae and slime molds and a number of other things that I'm forced to admit I know nothing about. He's famous in his own field, a man in his early sixties, very distinguished to look at and apparently a first-rate teacher. [. . .]"

**The black woman is part of a biosphere experiment in Arizona, and I seem to recall that her followers are almost like a cult.**

Colorado, actually:

> It jumped out at me in the first ten seconds of looking. Six days after this letter had been mailed, Lockyer had placed a series of four phone calls in one day to Lathrop, Colorado. One call had lasted for over forty minutes. I checked in my National Geographic atlas. Nathrop was a small town about seventy miles west of Colorado Springs. It lay on the Arkansas River with the Sawatch Range of the High Rockies rearing up to over fourteen thousand feet just to the west.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "Marcia graduated, and I thought she had taken a job somewhere on the West Coast. I didn't worry about her, because she was the most charismatic person I had ever met. She seemed able to talk the rest of the students into doing anything. It turned out that I was right, but I had underestimated her. The next thing I knew, I had a letter from another one of my students. He wanted to know what end-forms were possible when you started an ecosphere with a given mix of organisms. The answer, of course, is that today's theories are inadequate. No one knows where you'll finish. But it was the first hint I had that something had gone on beyond my lecture. I sent him a reply, and a week later in my In-Box at the university I found a letter with an odd stamp on it, like a caricature of a black-faced doll."
>
> "A golliwog," I said.
>
> "So I learned. I also realized that it looked a lot like Marcia. The letter said that I was the official founding father of the Habitat League. I've seen stuff like that before, silly student jokes. So it didn't worry me. But *then* I began to receive anonymous letters with the same stamp. And when I read those, I began to worry."
>
> "We saw one," I said. "It was sent to you but the mails fouled up the delivery."
>
> "The person who wrote them said that Marcia had set up her own organization within Ascend Forever, with its own chapters and its own sponsors for funding. She had organized a camp in Colorado—this one—and they were following my advice on setting up self-sustaining ecospheres that could be used as a model for space habitats. I replied to him, saying the Colorado mountains were not a bad site, but they weren't the best."

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I really enjoyed this story, and it was frustrating not being able to recall the details more clearly.

Comment: I'm curious - as she's the narrator, does she actually describe her appearance in the manner described?

Comment: @Adamant Huh? The narrator is the white woman (a private investigator named Rachel Banks), her appearance is not described in the passages I quoted. (You can read the whole story at the Archive link.) If my phrasing was misleading or ambiguous please let me know so I can fix it.

Comment: @user14111 - Ah, sorry. When you said “She narrates the story” I suppose I misinterpreted which of the previous instances of “she” it referred to.

Comment: @Adamant Thanks. I hope it's clearer now.